# Confusion Regarding Bayesian Mixture of Gaussians

Tags: bayesian, gaussian-mixture-distribution

Following is the screenshot from the paper "Variational Inference: A Review for Statisticians".

> [image]

---

I am having confusion understanding equations (7) and (8).

Can anyone please let me know whether my understanding regarding equation (7) is correct and if not, provide me the correct insight?

*Regarding equation (7):*

> [image]

---

*Regarding equation (8):*

- Why are we integrating only over latent variable μ and not c?
- What does the statement "The integrand in Equation (8) does not contain a separate factor for each μk. (Indeed, each μk appears in all n factors of the integrand.)" mean?

---

Could anyone provide me helpful resources to understand these equations better?

Comment: $c_i$s are integrated out. The summation is exactly doing that. As for the second statement, $c_i^\top \boldsymbol{\mu}$ is implicitly selecting the correct $\mu_k$ for each $x_i$ because $c_i$ is a vector with one 1 and zero everywhere else. No need to explicitly write a factor for each $\mu_k$